# How can I force UriBuilder to use https?

Tags: jersey-2.0, dropwizard, mod-proxy

I'm currently running Dropwizard behind Apache httpd acting as a reverse proxy, configured like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  <Location /api>
    ProxyPass "http://my.app.org:8080/api"
  <Location>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

With other `Location` settings serving static assets and some authentication thrown in. Now, httpd also performs SSL offloading, so my Dropwizard only receives the plain HTTP request.

In my Dropwizard API, I like to return a `Location` header indicating newly created resources:

```
@Path("/comment")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
class CommentResource() {
  @PUT
  fun create(@Context uri: UriInfo, entity: EventComment): Response {
    val stored: EventComment = createEntity(entity)
    return Response.created(uri.baseUriBuilder.path(MessageStream::class.java)
            .resolveTemplate("realmish", entity.realmId)
            .path(stored.id.toString()).build()).build()
}
```

This creates a `Response` with a `Location` header from `JerseyUriBuilder`:

```
Location http://my.app.org/api/messages/123
```

Which, on my SSL-only app, naturally fails to load (I'm actually surprised this didn't turn out to render as `http://my.app.org:8080/api/messages/123` - probably also the reason why `ProxyPassReverse` didn't help).

I know I can force the scheme to be https by using `baseUriBuilder.scheme("https")`, but this gets repetitive and is an easy source of errors.

Thus my **question**: how can I either make Jersey generate correct front-end URLs or successfully make httpd rewrite those generated by Dropwizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jersey, you can use a pre-matching [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9637) to rewrite the URI. For example

```
@PreMatching
public class SchemeRewriteFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        URI newUri = request.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder().scheme("https").build();
        request.setRequestUri(newUri);
    }
}
```

Then just register it with Jersey (Dropwizard)

```
env.jersey().register(SchemeRewriteFilter.class);
```

---

#### EDIT

The above only works when you use `uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder()`. If you want to use `uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()`, then you need to use the overloaded `setRequestUri` that accepts the base uri as the first arg.

```
URI newUri = request.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder().scheme("https").build();
URI baseUri = request.getUriInfo().getBaseUriBuilder().scheme("https").build();
request.setRequestUri(baseUri, newUri);
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to switch between http and https? Say sometimes i want to deploy my application in http(for testing purpose) with apache htppd as my proxy. If i override the request uri, it always returns HTTPS. Is there any way to switch?

Comment: @Jeevi you might just want to add a configuration flag. That's probably the easiest way. `if (rewrite) { rewrite(); }`.

Answer (score 0):

If using Jetty, then you can avoid the hacks by registering the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer` with your server. This will look at the `X-Forwarded-*` headers to build the base URI.

Sample using embedded Jetty:

```
Server jettyServer = new Server();
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
ServerConnector serverConnector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer, 
                                      new HttpConnectionFactory(config));
serverConnector.setPort(8080);
jettyServer.setConnectors(new Connector[] {serverConnector});
```

This seems to work whether or not you are behind a reverse proxy, so I don't know why it isn't just enabled by default.

Comment: Hm, that's funny. I'm using Dropwizard and the [docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#http) say `useForwardedHeaders` is what should be used *and* it defaults to `true`. Now, I still saw that issue, so maybe httpd wasn't passing the right headers? Let me check that.

Comment: @mabi Thanks! Your comment is very helpful. In fact in latest Dropwizard versions `useForwardedHeaders` is `false` by default and setting it to `true` helps